# JavaScript suggestions using props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I always find the built-in suggestions in vscode helpful to write code but for example, when I'm using react and I'm assigning some value to a variable, there are no suggestions from built-in methods or functions.

[image: check here to see what I mean]

There, it should display that I could use toLocaleString() for example, but it does not, the only suggestions are "abc" which is like having nothing, props.date is in fact a date object so it should suggest me that, if I add it manually it works just fine but since I don't have plenty of experience programming, at times those suggestions help me a lot to know what I can do, even find some things I didn't know before.

getFullYear() should be another suggestion but is nowhere to be seen either.

Is there a way to have my vscode give me suggestions of things I could use in those situations?

When I work with vanilla JS I think there is no issue but since I've been working with react lately I'm not entirely sure so give me a suggestion for vanilla js too if you can.

Comment: Well, it has no type information, it can't know whether `props.date` is indeed a date. If you want type information, you could migrate to TypeScript.

Comment: Is there no other option? I'm kind of learning so I don't want to use TypeScript. Would be helpful for me to get the suggestions when using props or in any other situation where this might happen.

Comment: @NicolasAlejandro what suggestions do you want? For all that vscode knows, `props.date` could be anything. Starting at `null` or `undefined` over some primitive value, a `Date` object, an `Array`, a `Promise`, a DOM-Node, or whatever else. So what properties/methods do you want vscode to suggest to you in this case? If you want any meaningful suggestions you need to describe to vscode what `props` is, what properties it has, and what they contain. You can use TypeScript for that, or Flow or jsdoc comments, but **you** have to provide that information to vscode to get meaningful  suggestions.

Comment: @Thomas I'm learning React and JS I don't want to learn TypeScript yet. If there is a solution for a beginner like me, what would you suggest? I want to stick using JS for now.
It's not a deal breaker to keep it as it is but since I'm learning, I find really helpful those suggestions because some times I can see what else I can do and do a quick research to read the documentation.

When I was writing JS it helped me a lot but when I'm using props some times I feel lost or that I did something wrong since nothing is showing up.

I don't know what jsdocs or flow are, what would you suggest?